# How to import CSV to KNIME in command line

Tags: knime

I want to import a CSV file to KNIME in command line. When I run a command line like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\KNIME\knime.exe" c:\temp\foo.csv
```

[image: Import a CSV]

A dialog pops up, but the button is grayed, I can't click finish. I'm new to KNIME, just installed it, does KNIME support importing CSV directly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you can import CSV files. That way you can open KNIME workflows. If you want to override a KNIME workflow's input data and (batch) execute the KNIME workflow, you should use flow variables as input and specify them in the command line: https://www.knime.com/faq#q12

```
-workflow.variable=my_csv_location,C:/tmp/foo.csv,String
```

Or something similar.

If you just want to import a CSV file to an existing workflow, just drag it on the editor area and it will add a CSV Reader node with the path set.

Comment: Thanks, I tried above parameter, it forces me to create a new workspace if the KNIME is in use. It says: the default workspace ..... is in use or cannot be created, please choose a different. Then I I choose a new name, but the CSV is not imported. Actually what I want is: import a CSV to the default workspace, but I can't drag it on the editor. Because I plan to integrate KNIME with a web tool. On the web, I'll create a link like this: foobar://knime/test.csv. When user clicks the link, a tool will invoke KNIME and pass test.csv to KNIME, then import the CSV automatically, that's my purpose.

Comment: Probably you should understand the concepts first.